# Payment addresses arent showing up on electrum

Tags: electrum

quick question.

Using the electrum wallet for my website checkout. But the addresses generated arent showing up in my electrum wallet?

was working fine last week and now its showing different wallet addresses that arent showing in my electrum wallet address section

Note I’m searching for the addresses payments have been made to that are linked to my seed / master key, but the addresses don’t show in my address list on electrum

Comment: Have you tried increasing gap limit in console with `wallet.change_gap_limit(N)` where N is number of receiving addresses?

Comment: Not I haven’t …. Will this show the address that the funds have been paid to tho? 

There’s about 10 payments to 10 different addresses all linked to my master key / seed. 

But searching for those addresses in electrum. They are not there.

Comment: If you see 20 right now in Electrum, run this command with N=30 to see more 10 addresses

Comment: Ok, but doing this will the addresses the money has been sent to appear? 
Which crypto woo generated (which electrum master key is linked to)

Comment: thanks for that input, but this did nothing to help the major question asked on my post

Comment: I am not sure. It's mostly related to gap limit. You can try increasing it. We are basically trying to see same number of addresses as website created using same master public key.

Comment: How many addresses do I need to create then, to see the addresses that the funds have been sent to mate?